# ¿Cómo comparar unidades de tiempo en Bash Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, script

estoy desarrollando un programa que lista los procesos en memoria que llevan mas de 1 minuto de CPU y tengo un problema al comparar las unidades de tiempo.

```
ps --no-headers -e | awk '{if ( $3 > TIEMPO ) print $0}'
```

El problema me viene al expresar "TIEMPO" para hacer la comparación, no me funciona poner un entero ( "1" por ejemplo), ni poniendo una cadena ("00:01:00"). Alguno sabe como hacer esta comparación, Muchas gracias

Comment: Podrias poner tu codigo para que pueda ayudarte a resolver el error. Creo que hace falta que declares la variable "TIEMPO".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra manera aun mas sencilla de hacerlo es hacer uso de la opción `-o` o `--format` del comando `ps`, la cual nos permite especificar nuestro propio formato de salida.
En este caso usaremos el mismo formato que viene por defecto en la opción `-e` que también es un sinónimo de la opcion `-A` (a mi parecer esta es mas cómoda ya que refleja *All*, apuntando así a todos los procesos del sistema) y añadiremos el argumento `times` que nos indica el tiempo de cpu en segundos, de esa forma si queremos saber si un proceso lleva mas de 1 minuto en cpu lo único que debemos hacer es usar un `if` de ***awk*** para validar que la columna de `times` debe tener mas de 60 segundos:

```sh
ps -A --format pid,tty,times,time,comm | awk '{if($3 > 60) print $0}'

# O si quieres quitarle la cabecera como en el ejemplo de tu pregunta

ps -A --no-headers --format pid,tty,times,time,comm | awk '{if($3 > 60) print $0}'
```

Comment: Hola. Puedes editar la respuesta y colocar todo junto. No tiene mucho sentido dejar dos respuestas separadas siendo el mismo usuario.

Comment: Crei que valian dos respuestas, para dos soluciones completamente diferentes.

Comment: @Adriànn ¿por que el servicio web permite que un mismo usuario de multiples respuestas si es una mala idea ?

Comment: Muchas gracias, entendí lo que querías decir y funciona perfectamente gracias :)